# Read from offset per partition in kafka spring boot

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have create topic `topic-99` with 5 partition and replication factor 3.

On first call, i am able to get the offset of each partition as follows:

```
topic-99-4: 14026
topic-99-3: 13661
topic-99-2: 13178
topic-99-1: 12183
topic-99-0: 13192
```

The code for fetching above is as follows:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/kafka/consumer/{topicName}")
    public void getkafkaTopicStatus(
            @Parameter(description = "Topic name", required = true) @PathVariable String topicName) throws Exception {
        KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(kafkaConsumerConfig.consumerConfigs());
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));
        Set<TopicPartition> assignment;
        while ((assignment = consumer.assignment()).isEmpty()) {
            consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500));
        }
        consumer.endOffsets(assignment).forEach((partition, offset) -> System.out.println(partition + ": " + offset));
        consumer.close();
    }
```

Now i want to start consumer listener container from the `latest offset per partition` so that only new data is read from topic.
The current code for such listener is as follows:

```
public class OffsetConsumer implements AcknowledgingMessageListener<Integer, String>, ConsumerSeekAware {

    private ConsumerSeekCallback consumerSeekCallback;


    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

            consumerSeekCallback.seek("topicname", record.partition(), record.offset());
// expects to get latest records only but how to assign the above values fetched??

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback consumerSeekCallback) {
        this.consumerSeekCallback = consumerSeekCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> map, ConsumerSeekCallback consumerSeekCallback) {

        // nothing is needed here for this program
    }

    @Override
    public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> map, ConsumerSeekCallback consumerSeekCallback) {

        // nothing is needed here for this program
    }

}
```

I am not sure how to use the values i have in listener so that get only latest records in `onMessage` method

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all that complexity.

See the callback javadocs:

```java
/**
 * Perform a seek relative to the start, end, or current position. When called
 * from {@link ConsumerSeekAware#onPartitionsAssigned(Map, ConsumerSeekCallback)}
 * or from {@link ConsumerSeekAware#onIdleContainer(Map, ConsumerSeekCallback)}
 * perform the seek immediately on the consumer. When called from elsewhere, queue
 * the seek operation. The queued seek will occur after any pending offset
 * commits. The consumer must be currently assigned the specified partition.
 * @param topic the topic.
 * @param partition the partition.
 * @param offset the offset; positive values are relative to the start, negative
 * values are relative to the end, unless toCurrent is true.
 * @param toCurrent true for the offset to be relative to the current position
 * rather than the beginning or end.
 * @since 2.3
 */
void seekRelative(String topic, int partition, long offset, boolean toCurrent);
```

Something like this.

```java
@Override
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
    assignments.keySet().forEach(tp -> callback.seekRelative(tp.topic(), tp.partition(), -1, false));
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek

This will read the last record. If you only want new records then

```
callback.seekToEnd(assignments.keySet());
```

```java
/**
 * Perform a seek to end operation. When called from
 * {@link ConsumerSeekAware#onPartitionsAssigned(Map, ConsumerSeekCallback)} or
 * from {@link ConsumerSeekAware#onIdleContainer(Map, ConsumerSeekCallback)}
 * perform the seek immediately on the consumer. When called from elsewhere, queue
 * the seek operation to the consumer for each {@link TopicPartition}. The queued
 * seek(s) will occur after any pending offset commits. The consumer must be
 * currently assigned the specified partition(s).
 * @param partitions the {@link TopicPartition}s.
 * @since 2.3.4
 */
default void seekToEnd(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Comment: I just re-read your question; `>only new data is read from topic` - see the edit to my answer; use `seekToEnd()`.

Comment: @Gary.Thanks a lot for letting me know these methods., actually the things is i have quite a big file and we divide it into chunks and process in loop,so was implementing checkpoints so that we come to know each chunk is pushed into producer.hence getting latest offset by temporary consumer after data is pushed into producer and use this knowledge in final consumer to push it into sink dbs.